# Best practice for wrapping C libraries in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I've recently started a project in Erlang after many years I've touched it last time.

I need to use some POSIX calls that are not available in stdlib or 3rd side wrappers, like, for instance sys/mount.h

mount call (man 2 mount) uses some int flags for mount parameters.
They are defined in some headers.

What's approach is better: to use integer flags / defines in Erlang wrappes, or it's more safe to use a list of atoms for arguments like this and parse them in C?

Are there any active port/driver wrapper generator for Erlang?
I know about dryverl, ic, etc, but they looks abandoned and also
it's  inconvenient to write descriptions for functions in XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better approach is to use a list of atoms in API functions which you provide for programmers and then transform them to integer flags in wrapper itself. Then pass them to C as integer.